# Onclick with window.open _self

Tags: javascript

Basically just trying to get this form to use onclick to open the link in the current window...i thought I would use the _self option with window.open but I am getting no luck.

```
    <form data-theme="b" name="form21">
   <label style="font-size:18px; width:100%" data-theme="b" for="select-choice-1" class="select">Select your kennel's state:</label>
   <select name="menu" id="select-choice-1">
      <option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Arizona</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Arkansas</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">California</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Maine</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Michigan</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Nebraska</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">New York</option>
   </select>
</form>
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-hidden"  onClick="window.open(document.form21.menu.options[document.form21.menu.selectedIndex].value);"  aria-disabled="false">Go</button>
```

Comment: If you want to make a link open in the same page, why not just use an `<a href=""></a>`?  Or just set `window.location.href = '...';`.

Comment: Wow, can devices be licked now!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `location.href` in order to redirect from your own page:

```
        <form data-theme="b" name="form21">
   <label style="font-size:18px; width:100%" data-theme="b" for="select-choice-1" class="select">Select your kennel's state:</label>
   <select name="menu" id="select-choice-1">
      <option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Arizona</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Arkansas</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">California</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Maine</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Michigan</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Nebraska</option>
<option value="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">New York</option>
   </select>
</form>
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn-hidden"  onClick="location.href = document.form21.menu.options[document.form21.menu.selectedIndex].value;"  aria-disabled="false">Go</button>
```